# Buffered Reader Throwing Exception

Tags: java, loops, bufferedreader, ioexception, bufferedwriter

I want to print hello for "t" number of times. So, i have written this code snippet.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Buff
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        while(t-->0)
            bw.write("hello");

    }
}
```

It outputs an exception

```
Buff.java:11: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                String t = br.readLine();
                                      ^
Buff.java:14: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                        bw.write("hello");
```

**Please Help !!!**
PS : It doesn't help even if i put throws IOException

Comment: "_PS : It doesn't help even if i put throws IOException_" – And where did you place this throws? Because `public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {...}` should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch possible exceptions (in this case `IOException`).

The basic syntax looks like this:

```
try {
    //Your code here
}
catch(IOException e) {
    //What do you want to do when something went wrong?
}
```

In your case, the following code will work:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Buff
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
            
            int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            //Closing Readers and Writers when not needed anymore is good-practice
            br.close();

            //"-->" wasn't working for me in this case
            while(t > 0) {
                bw.write("hello\n");
                t--;
            }
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
        }

        //Catching possible exceptions
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```